# Angularjs - Firefox does not open blob url in a new tab

Tags: angularjs, firefox

I have the following code working fine in Chrome and IE. User clicks on an anchor tag and the code gets executed after which a pdf file is rendered in a new tab with the url blob:http://localhost:57389/5aee262a-8bc9-4943-b67f-7b76aeef4b99

```
vme.loadAttachment = function (attachment) {
    taskService.getAttachmentContent(attachment.Name)
        .then(function (response) {
            var file = new Blob([response], { type: attachment.Type });
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file);
            }
            else {
                var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                window.open($sce.trustAsResourceUrl(objectUrl), _blank");
            }
       })
};
```

However on Firefox, the new tab is opened but closes immediately on its own.  Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: did the anchor's click event leads to file download?

Comment: Yes. Verified that I could see the response in the network tab.

Comment: maybe change the way firefox do with pdf files will resolve this.there is a setting to set firefox to preview the pdf files downloaded.

Comment: Tested on another machine and pdf loads fine in another tab. Weird..all the while it was just an issue on my machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This thing happened to me today. I have several different VM snapshots that I use to test different "clients", and I got two of these where PDF would not open - the browser briefly flashed and the PDF did not appear.

In the end, it was an ad blocker (ABP). Simply telling it to ignore the website domain allowed PDFs to appear correctly.

Comment: Ah yes. That fixed it for me also.

Comment: Thanks, you save me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: code working before (still working in chrome), does not work anymore. I think the problem is related to firefox forbidding to open blob URLs from script - but I couldn't verify it. But if you try to execute `window.open(myBlobUrl)` from the console, you will see:

> Error: Access to 'blob:http://localhost:8000/53dc4cba-329a-4479-b685-d0257425b318' from script denied

### Solution / Workaround

The only solution/workaround for me was to create a URL in the backend service, which provides the PDF directly.

#### Server

Add these http headers to the handler that responds to the URL at which the PDF can be accessed:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename = filename.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

#### Angular View

```
<a ng-href="{{ pathToPdf }}" target='_blank'>my link</a>
```

#### Angular Controller

```
$scope.pathToPdf = MyPdfService.getPdfUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

check browser popup settings. That might be one of the issue.

Comment: Already did that. If it was a popup setting, there would be a notification from firefox. In this case, the new tab opens for a split second and closes on its own.